# special characters causing problem in perl

Tags: perl, sed

I want to substitute all occurences of  string in a file as follows :

`printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %d and leaves at %d\n", MYTHREAD, start, end);`

with

`printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %dlf\n", MYTHREAD, (double)start, (double)end);`

The command I have been trying is

```
perl -pi -e "s/printf(\"thread %d: enters barrier at %d and leaves at %d\\\n\", MYTHREAD, start, end);/printf(\"thread %d: enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %lf\\\n\", MYTHREAD,(double)start/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (double)end/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)/g" bt_copy.c
```

But I get errors. Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: what errors do you get, also have you used strict/warnings/diagnostics?

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %d and leaves at %d\\n", MYTHREAD, start, end);/printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %lf\\n", MYTHREAD,(double)start/CLOCKS_PER_SEC"
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ")end"
 (Missing operator before end?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %d and leaves at %d\\n", MYTHREAD, start, end);/printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %lf\\n", MYTHREAD,(double)start/CLOCKS_PER_SEC"

Comment: Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors. this was the error I got

Comment: Using single-quotes around the program is generally easier than double quotes.  Probably time to put that into a script file, or at least split it over several lines.

Comment: Have you tried simply using your editor to perform this simple search/replace? What obstacles did you encounter when you tried?

Comment: i'm editing this over  a remote machine.. gedit does not work via ssh here :(

Comment: @Sharat Chandra: `vim` and `nano` work over ssh (as does `gedit` with X-forwarding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want using `sed`.

```
sed 's/printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %d and leaves at %d\\n", MYTHREAD, start, end);/printf("thread %d: enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %dlf\\n", MYTHREAD, (double)start, (double)end);/' bt_copy.c
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the slash `/` character as the delimiter for your `s///` expression, but you also have the slash character in your replacement pattern

```
printf(\"thread %d: enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %lf\\\n\",
MYTHREAD,(double)start/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (double)end/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
```

You might try using a different delimiter, like

```
perl -pi -e 's! ...pattern ... ! ...replace ...!g' input_file
```

(Also if you are using a Unixy shell like bash, prefer single quotes to double quotes in specifying your one-line program. You will have less shell meta character interpolation related headaches that way).

Comment: Also, the parentheses inside the pattern are probably not doing what OP wants.  Sharat can decide which of `/printf\(...\)/` or `/\Qprintf(...)\E/` they like better.

Answer (score 2):

From the C perspective, consider the merits of:

```
void pr_barrier_time(int thread, int start, int end)
{
     printf("thread %d enters barrier at %lf and leaves at %lf\n",
            thread, (double)start/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (double)end/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

And edit your code so the calls become:

```
pr_barrier_time(MYTHREAD, start, end);
```

You can even add an automatic 'fflush()' after the 'printf()' with the function call; much harder to do with the inline `printf()` statements.